# Vuze import Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, swt, invocationtargetexception, vuze

Here I am trying to import Vuze-SVN to Eclipse. I followed the instructions on http://wiki.vuze.com/w/Using_Eclipse. I think I solved swt.jar version issues, because the error I am encountering now is different than previous swt version issues. When I try to run AZ-SVN:

```
file:/home/ozge/Documents/swt.jar ; file:/home/ozge/workspace/AZ_SVN/bin/ ; file:/home/ozge/workspace/AZ_SVN/azureus2/lib/apple-extensions.jar ; file:/home/ozge/workspace/AZ_SVN/azureus2/lib/swt-carbon.jar ; file:/home/ozge/workspace/AZ_SVN/azureus2/lib/swt-cocoa.jar ; file:/home/ozge/workspace/AZ_SVN/uis/lib/commons-cli.jar ; file:/home/ozge/workspace/AZ_SVN/uis/lib/junit.jar ; file:/home/ozge/workspace/AZ_SVN/uis/lib/log4j.jar ; file:/home/ozge/Desktop/comp491/swt-xosx.jar ; file:/home/ozge/workspace/AZ_SVN/azureus2/lib/swt-win32.jar ; file:/home/ozge/Desktop/Azureus/vuze/swt.jar ; file:/home/ozge/Desktop/Azureus/vuze/swt/swt32.jar ; file:/home/ozge/Desktop/Azureus/vuze/swt/swt64.jar ; file:/home/ozge/Desktop/Azureus/vuze/
    DEBUG::Wed Dec 18 18:57:08 EET 2013  BC Provider 'BC_VUZE' initialised successfully (loaded from file:/home/ozge/workspace/AZ_SVN/bin/org/bouncycastle/jce/provider/BouncyCastleProvider.class)
    changeLocale: *Default Language* != English (United States). Searching without country..
    changeLocale: Searching for language English in *any* country..
    changeLocale: no message properties for Locale 'English (United States)' (en_US), using 'English (default)'
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:534)
        at org.gudy.azureus2.ui.swt.Main.<init>(Main.java:114)
        at org.gudy.azureus2.ui.swt.Main.main(Main.java:325)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
        at com.aelitis.azureus.launcher.MainExecutor$1.run(MainExecutor.java:37)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
        no swt-gtk-4332 in java.library.path
        no swt-gtk in java.library.path
        /home/ozge/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-gtk-4332.so: /home/ozge/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-gtk-4332.so: ELF file data encoding not little-endian (Possible cause: endianness mismatch)
        Can't load library: /home/ozge/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-gtk.so

        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at org.gudy.azureus2.ui.swt.mainwindow.SWTThread.<init>(SWTThread.java:85)
        at org.gudy.azureus2.ui.swt.mainwindow.SWTThread.createInstance(SWTThread.java:64)
        at com.aelitis.azureus.ui.swt.Initializer.<init>(Initializer.java:163)
        ... 12 more
```

What is the problem now?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a problem in your java.library.path

Search for your SWT lib and setup your path.
Maybe you'll have to reinstall SWT and or Java.

Answer (score 0):

The Vuze project was lured into the Ads with pro-plus payment options but luckily some of the original developers took a fork before leaving and created BiglyBT. Their first fork is mostly the same except: it's not full of adverts, doesn't contain any of the premium features and doesn't hassle you about upgrading.

https://github.com/BiglySoftware/BiglyBT

There's more information about differences between BiglyBT and Vuze:

https://www.ghacks.net/2017/08/05/biglybt-new-vuze-based-torrent-client-without-ads/

I tried to build Vuze in Eclipse the last time I got pee'd off with all their bugs but the project was a bit of a mess, had Bugzilla (the worst bug tracker in the world IMO) and I couldn't get it to work either: a rabbit hole of dependency issues.

Gave BiglyBT a go and got it up and running quite easily. It's all GitHub, openness and no BugZilla now which is a great improvement.